# Where does Rei's Minimap store your waypoints?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

In what file does Rei's Minimap store its waypoint data?

I recently updated a server's modpack (from FTB Beta to Direwolf20's pack) and the waypoints disappeared in the process. I've combed through the folders of the backup from before I did the update and I can't find anything that looks remotely like storage for the waypoints. My objective is to, if possible, import everyone's waypoint data into the updated server setup.

Comment: I wonder why I never thought of asking this before.  +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, they're stored client-side, so you can't restore players' waypoints on your side. They're in `mods/rei_minimap` in the minecraft folder. You should have a bunch of .points files in there.

Each file stores the waypoints for a single dimension in a world. Multiplayer waypoints are stored by server address, so if your server is on a consumer machine with a dynamic IP address, you should set up a hostname for it so players don't keep losing their waypoints.

Comment: Oh! Of course they would be stored client side! That should have occurred to me. Well I can at least provide instructions to import them from the old FTBBETAA client-side folder structure to the new Direwold20 folder structure. That also explains why they disappeared even though the hostname is unchanged.

Comment: Well, storing them serverside *would* make sense. That way, hostname/IP address changes wouldn't reset the waypoints, and map resets would. Not doing that makes it compatible with vanilla servers though.

Comment: **NB** the file is named for the world's file system *folder* (not the world name,). So (say) copying a world to a new folder requires separately copying the waypoint files based on names matching the new save folder.

Comment: This does not appear to be the case anymore for Rei's 3.6 for 1.7.10. I can't find any .points files anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

They are stored in the `.minecraft\mods\rei_minimap` using the .points extension, with a separate file for each map/server and dimension (including Mystcraft ones).

The format is `[Map/save].DIM[#].points`

Answer (score 0):

1.7.10, I found the reiminimap details stored in the  config/rei_minimap directory.

But it always used New World.DIM0.points for every world I created.

I found that if you have a unique savename for the world, (go back and rename it if youve just used default New World).

**BUT you must add a directory of the same name to the config/rei_minimap directory.**

EXAMPLE: My Saved World is called "MYTEST World"
You need to add this as a directory and get the config/rei_minimap/MYTEST World directory.

Mininmap does not seem to add any files to it thou, it still creates the points file in the config/rei_minimap directory in this case it created "MYTEST World.DIM0.points"

Hope this is the case for anyone else.

Comment: Funny no Ive done first one its seems to be saving seperate files now. Maybe it was a bug on my machine