# How do I get Rei's Minimap waypoints from inside the .minecraft folder?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

So I read [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/101958/where-does-reis-minimap-store-your-waypoints/110511#110511) and I did what it said, but when I tried to open the `.points` files, it either said it was empty or that it wasn't supported. What do I do?

Comment: IIRC either in the mods folder of config

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just tried to click the file open. Since it has a `.points` file extension, that won't work on most operating systems. You need to open it in a text editor.

Answer (score 1):

Simply double-clicking on the points folder is not going to get you anywhere since such a file extension is not supported by any known program.  You will need to right click on the file and choose the Open With option if it is available.  A lot of the time on these really strange database files however, that isn't an option.  So double click it and select the second option which should read: "Select a program from a list of installed programs" then hit OK.

Use Notepad to open it.

Copy and paste by opening the new installation the same way and so forth.